# Printing/Debugging libc++ STL with Xcode/LLDB

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, lldb, libc++

I'm trying to use LLDB within Xcode 8 to debug very basic STL. I used to be able to print a vector like this:

```
p myvector[0]
```

to see whatever was in the first vector index. Now when I do that, I get this error:

```
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZNSt3__16vectorI9my_classNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEixEm
```

Instead, I have to type this:

```
p myvector.__begin_[0]
```

in order to get any output.

I tried importing the libcxx.py and unordered_multi.py scripts from the LLDB svn repository but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Has anyone been able to get any useful output from LLDB with libc++?

Comment: Did you compile with debug info? Can you provide a self contained reproducer?

Comment: Of course debug info is enabled. :) Here's a dumb project that can reproduce the issue. Just set a breakpoint on the std::cout line and run the lldb command "p myVector[0]" when it hits. You'll get an error. If you do "p myVector.__begin_[0]" instead it'll print nicely. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntjywxabxj3e4mc/Crap.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`[]` is an operator method on `std::vector`, so to print the expression you want, lldb would have to be able to call the `[]` method.  The problem here is that the STL on OS X is aggressive about inlining everything it can, and not wasting space producing out of line copies of the same functions.  That's great for optimized code, but not so good for debugging because it leaves the debugger with no `[]` operator to call.  That's the error message you are seeing.

If you just want to see the elements in this vector, you can use the lldb **"STL data formatters"** to do this work for you.  They know how most STL types are laid out, and can print the elements of most container types.  For instance:

```
(lldb) expr my_vec[0]
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZNSt3__16vectorI3FooNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEixEm
```

but:

```
(lldb) expr my_vec
(std::__1::vector<Foo, std::__1::allocator<Foo> >) $0 = size=2 {
  [0] = (var1 = 10, var2 = 20)
  [1] = (var1 = 10, var2 = 20)
}
```

There is also another command **"frame variable"** which can inspect static objects, and hooks into the data formatters.  It can't call functions and do other more complex expression parser tasks, but it does know how to use the STL data formatters to retrieve individual elements:

```
(lldb) frame var my_vec[1]
(Foo) my_vec[1] = (var1 = 10, var2 = 20)
```

You can even use frame var's `-L` option to locate the elements of the vector, and then you can cast the address to pass it to other functions:

```
(lldb) frame var -L my_vec[1]
0x0000000100100348: (Foo) my_vec[1] = {
0x0000000100100348:   var1 = 10
0x000000010010034c:   var2 = 20
}
(lldb) expr printf("%d\n", ((class Foo *) 0x0000000100100348)->var1)
10
(int) $3 = 3
```

Another way to work around this for debugging - if you are using C++11 - is by putting:

```
template class std::vector<MyClass>
```

in your code somewhere.  That will instruct the compiler to emit out-of-line copies of all the template functions for this specialization.  That isn't a great general solution, and you only want to do it for debug builds, but it does let you call these functions and use them in complex expressions.

Comment: Very thorough answer Jim, I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior on Linux (Ubuntu 16.10) with clang/lldb 3.9. But gcc/gdb have no trouble with `(gdb) p my_vec[0]`. I wonder what they're doing differently.

Comment: IME, the combination of clang/STL is much more aggressive about inlining, even at -O0, that gcc tends to be.

Comment: According to a [llvm-dev post](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/lldb-dev/2017-January/011873.html): "Yes, this is a problem with our STL, we are forcing inlining and we need to fix this on libc++ side, it is scheduled, but we haven’t come to it yet."

Comment: If I have a vector of 512 samples, doing `expr my_vec` only print the first 255 elements. How can I set the number of element to display?

Comment: Either pass `-A` to the expr command (in which case you have to run `expr -A -- my_vec`) or to change the default value do: `(lldb) settings set target.max-children-count <SOME NUMBER>`

Comment: can someone please elaborate on that last point, "template class std::vector<MyClass>" and how that helps?  I tried to add a similar line like that and I got compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

The similar problem also happens with me: `error: Couldn't lookup symbols:`

My solution is to explicitly use the questioned function somewhere in a source code.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Vector : std::vector<T>
{
    Vector(size_t n)
    : std::vector<T>{n}
    {}

    T& operator[](size_t n)
    { return std::vector<T>::operator[](n); }
};

struct XXX
{
    int x;
};

void func()
{
    std::vector<XXX> a{10};
    Vector<XXX> b{10};

    auto x = b[0]; // gcc will produce an assembler code of operator[] for debug purpose
    1;  // as a break point
}
```

Set a breakpoint on the line of 1; and run it.

```
(lldb) p a[0]
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZNSt3__16vectorI3XXXNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEixEm

(lldb) p b[0]
(XXX) $0 = (x = 0)
```

Bingo!! Does the function exist in a TEXT block?

```
(lldb) image lookup -r -n 'XXX.*operator'
1 match found in /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx:
        Address: sandbox[0x00000001000011f0] (sandbox.__TEXT.__text + 256)
        Summary: sandbox`Vector<XXX>::operator[](unsigned long) at main.cpp:19
```

I am not sure, but I had learned this before. In a debugging stage, instead of production stage. If we set a breakpoint on a line in a function of a template, what would a debugger do? Setting breakpoints, actually replacing some existing assembler code with trap or jump, here and there everywhere the template is applied? Or just setting a single breakpoint in a function? It is written as a template. So it should be inlined in a production stage. In a debugging stage, however, the function is not inlined and written as a normal function. Please do not simply believe what I say here. Please confirm by yourself. Consult documentation of `gcc,` `clang,` and `lldb.`

`#include <vector>` of MacOS 10.13.6, Xcode Version 9.4.1 has a macro `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY`:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::reference
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::operator[](size_type __n)
{
    _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__n < size(), "vector[] index out of bounds");
    return this->__begin_[__n];
}
```

The `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY` is defined in `#include <__config>` as:

```
#define _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __attribute__ ((__visibility__("hidden"), __always_inline__))
```

Such keywords `hidden` and `__always_inline__` seem to control behavior.

When I added `inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY` to the sample solution code above:

```
    inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    T& operator[](size_t n)
    { return std::vector<T>::operator[](n); }
```

resulted in:

```
(lldb) p b[0]
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __ZN6VectorI3XXXEixEm
```

I hope that help and somebody look into much more deeply.

Comment: This technique is awesome for custom containers (not STL) that get inlined! Just cast to void the first element accessed via `[]` operator.